# Cancan user permission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am using cancan for permissions and I would like it so users cannot see other users when visiting their profile/users page. User should only be able to see themselves.

In my ability.rb file I have

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
   user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

   if user.role? :admin
     can :manage, :all
   elsif user.role? :rookie 
     can [:update, :destroy], [Album, Photo, User]
     can :read, :all
   end

  can :manage, Album, :profile => { :user_id => user.id }
  can :manage, Photo, :profile => { :user_id => user.id }
  can :manage, Video, :profile => { :user_id => user.id }
  can :manage, Comment, :blog => { :profile => { :user_id => user.id } }
  can :manage, User, :id => user.id
 end
end
```

In my users_controller I have

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!
load_and_authorize_resource 

 def index
   @user = current_user
 end

 def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

The above usually works but since user is the primary model I am not sure how I can resolve this. Rails gives me the error

```
undefined method `user_id'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
#ability.rb:
can :manage, User, :id => user.id
```

Comment: worked but i am sill able to see others users? Any suggestions?

Comment: My roles are rookie and admin

Comment: Can you post controller code with all before_filters? Also, are your resources (current_site and user) nested and associated properly?

Comment: I have updated code above and yes current_site is nested correctly in current)user is being called though devise.

Comment: @SimonBagreev, usually user_id works. Have a similar situation and :id works just fine. Why is this so? is it because of custome userscontroller?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that most users start with role **:rookie** and you have ability

```
can :read, :all
```

for users with role **:rookie.** Then this means that **all :rookie users** will be able to **read**
 all resources.